# ogr2gui geojson to csv do not export coordinates

Tags: geojson, csv, ogr2ogr

I tried to convert ogr2gui to convert geojson files to csv. The geojson file contains point data only. The resulting csv only contains attribute data, no coordinates.

Is there a way to get the coordinates from geojson file using ogr2ogr?

Comment: Qgis 2.4 can do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure which GDAL version ogr2gui is using but with a current ogr2ogr it is for sure possible.

Read first the driver manual page http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html

Layer creation options:

> GEOMETRY (Starting with GDAL 1.6.0): By default, the geometry of a
>   feature written to a .csv file is discarded. It is possible to export
>   the geometry in its WKT representation by specifying GEOMETRY=AS_WKT.
>   It is also possible to export point geometries into their X,Y,Z
>   components (different columns in the csv file) by specifying
>   GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ, GEOMETRY=AS_XY or GEOMETRY=AS_YX. The geometry
>   column(s) will be prepended to the columns with the attributes values.

Let's make a test by reading some geojson from a WFS service

```
ogr2ogr -f csv test.csv -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=og:archsites&outputformat=application/json"
```

The result looks like this

```
WKT,cat,str1,bbox
"POINT (593493 4914730)",1,Signature Rock,"(4:593493,4914730,593493,4914730)"
"POINT (591950 4923000)",2,No Name,"(4:591950,4923000,591950,4923000)"
"POINT (589860 4922000)",3,Canyon Station,"(4:589860,4922000,589860,4922000)"
"POINT (590400 4922820)",4,Spearfish Creek,"(4:590400,4922820,590400,4922820)"
"POINT (593549 4925500)",5,No Name,"(4:593549,4925500,593549,4925500)"
"POINT (600375 4925235)",6,Prairie Site,"(4:600375,4925235,600375,4925235)"
"POINT (606635 4920773)",7,Jensen Pass,"(4:606635,4920773,606635,4920773)"
```